# PHP Excel import to MYSQL database working fine on localhost but not on online server

Tags: php, mysql, excel, database, import

PHP Excel import to MYSQL database working fine on localhost but not on online server.
I want to import a database from an excel sheet. I have written a piece of code in PHP where a user select an excel file and import it. My code is working fine on localhost but I am having problem doing the same on server online.

```
<?php

include_once("db_connect.php");
require_once('vendor/php-excel-reader/excel_reader2.php');
require_once('vendor/SpreadsheetReader.php');

if (isset($_POST["import"]))
{

  $allowedFileType = ['application/vnd.ms-excel','text/xls','text/xlsx','application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'];

  if(in_array($_FILES["file"]["type"],$allowedFileType)){

        $targetPath = 'uploads/'.$_FILES['file']['name'];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $targetPath);

        $Reader = new SpreadsheetReader($targetPath);

        $sheetCount = count($Reader->sheets());
        for($i=0;$i<$sheetCount;$i++)

        {

            $Reader->ChangeSheet($i);

            foreach ($Reader as $Row)
            {
                 $u_id = "";
                if(isset($Row[0])) {
                    $u_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$Row[0]);
                }

                $u_name = "";
                if(isset($Row[1])) {
                    $u_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$Row[1]);
                }

                $s_name = "";
                if(isset($Row[2])) {
                    $s_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$Row[2]);
                }


                if (!empty($u_id) || !empty($u_name) || !empty($s_name)) {
                    $query = "insert into school_list(user_id,user_name,school_name) values('".$u_id."','".$u_name."','".$s_name."')";
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

                    if (! empty($result)) {
                        $type = "success";
                        $message = "Excel Data Imported into the Database";
                    } else {
                        $type = "error";
                        $message = "Problem in Importing Excel Data";
                    }
                }
             }

         }
  }
  else
  { 
        $type = "error";
        $message = "Invalid File Type. Upload Excel File.";
  }
}
?>
```

I have an error 
This page isn’t working
******.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: do you have an error message ?

Comment: yes "This page isn’t working *****.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500"

Comment: do you have the same version of php installed on the server you have on localhost?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements. Escaping is not enough!

Comment: you have to check the php log and apache log . may be the problem come from something else and your code is running normal

Comment: tryr to add this to your php file  :  **error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');**

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI I have tried adding error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'on'); and it show me : "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'ZipArchive' not found in ___{file name}"

Comment: You have to install or activate zip extension on your server

Comment: that depend on the php version on your server .

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI i have Installed but still it is showing the same errors

Comment: what is the error , may be you have a lot of extension that need to be installed

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'ZipArchive' not found in /home/rpa16cfpf0mt/public_html/goodluck_sales/adminarea/excel/vendor/SpreadsheetReader_XLSX.php:217 Stack trace: #0 /home/rpa16cfpf0mt/public_html/goodluck_sales/adminarea/excel/vendor/SpreadsheetReader.php(166): SpreadsheetReader_XLSX->__construct('uploads/schooll...') #1 /home/rpa16cfpf0mt/public_html/goodluck_sales/adminarea/excel/insert_school.php(21): SpreadsheetReader->__construct('uploads/schooll...') #2 {main} thrown in /home/rpa16cfpf0mt/public_html/goodluck_sales/adminarea/excel/vendor/SpreadsheetReader_XLSX.php on line 217

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI see this is the complete error I am getting

Comment: what version of PHPExcel are you using ?

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI thank you sooo much you saved me from a very big trouble

Comment: It is working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'ZipArchive' not found in
>   /home/rpa16cfpf0mt/public_html/goodluck_sales/adminarea/excel/vendor/SpreadsheetReader_XLSX.php:217
>   Stack trace: #0

It seems that you have to install the Zip extension.

About zip extension, [check the official page](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/book.zip.php)

Comment: After install I also have to activate the that zip archive. That can be done by going to SELECT PHP VERSION in Cpanel and tick the checkbox besides zip.